# having error while declaring multiple entities in solr

Tags: tomcat, solr

i have just started learning solr. i have installed apache tomcat server and solr 3.5. I have successfully configured solr for searching data from oracle database for one entity. I am having problem when i am adding two entities in the data-config.xml and adding the fields in the solr schema.xml.I configured my data-config.xml like this...

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource name="JdbcDataSource" 
        driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.168.1.3:1521/orcl" 
        user="SSOHANI" 
        password="Ssohani123"/>

    <document name="doc">
        <entity name="PROJECTS" 
                query="select PROJECTS.ID, PROJECTS.BATCH_ID, PROJECTS.OPERATION, PROJECTS.NAME,
                PROJECTS.DESCRIPTION, PROJECTS.ESTIMATED_COST, PROJECTS.GRANTOR_AGENCY_ID,
                PROJECTS.GRANTEE_AGENCY_ID, PROJECTS.PROJECT_STATUS_ID,
                PROJECTS.PROJECT_TYPE_ID, PROJECTS.START_DATE, PROJECTS.END_DATE,
                NVL(PROJECTS.TRACS_PARENT_PROJECT_ID,0) TRACS_PARENT_PROJECT_ID,
                NVL(PROJECTS.STATE_PARENT_PROJECT_ID,0) STATE_PARENT_PROJECT_ID,
                NVL(PROJECTS.PLAN_ID,0) PLAN_ID,
                NVL(PROJECTS.PLAN_ID_TYPE,0) PLAN_ID_TYPE,
                NVL(PROJECTS.TRACS_ID,0) TRACS_ID,
                NVL(PROJECTS.STATE_ID,0) STATE_ID,
                PROJECTS.VALID, PROJECTS.APPLIED,
                NVL(PROJECTS.COMMENTS,'NULL') COMMENTS,
                PROJECTS.GENERATED_PLAN_ID, PROJECTS.TRACS_PROJECT_ID,
                PROJECTS.STATE_PLAN_ID from SSOHANI.PROJECTS" >

        <field column="ID" name="projects_id" />
        <field column="BATCH_ID" name="projects_batch_id" />
        <field column="OPERATION" name="projects_operation" />
        <field column="NAME" name="projects_name" />
        <field column="DESCRIPTION" name="projects_description" />
        <field column="ESTIMATED_COST" name="projects_estimated_cost" />
        <field column="GRANTOR_AGENCY_ID" name="projects_grantor_agency_id" />
        <field column="GRANTEE_AGENCY_ID" name="projects_grantee_agency_id" />
        <field column="PROJECT_STATUS_ID" name="projects_project_status_id" />
        <field column="PROJECT_TYPE_ID" name="projects_project_type_id" />
        <field column="START_DATE" name="projects_start_date" />
        <field column="END_DATE" name="projects_end_date" />
        <field column="TRACS_PARENT_PROJECT_ID" name="projects_tracs_parent_project_id" />
        <field column="STATE_PARENT_PROJECT_ID" name="projects_state_parent_project_id" />
        <field column="PLAN_ID" name="projects_plan_id" />
        <field column="PLAN_ID_TYPE" name="projects_plan_id_type" />
        <field column="TRACS_ID" name="projects_tracs_id" />
        <field column="STATE_ID" name="projects_state_id" />
        <field column="VALID" name="projects_valid" />
        <field column="APPLIED" name="projects_applied" />
        <field column="COMMENTS" name="projects_comments" />
        <field column="GENERATED_PLAN_ID" name="projects_generated_plan_id" />
        <field column="TRACS_PROJECT_ID" name="projects_tracs_project_id" />
        <field column="STATE_PLAN_ID" name="projects_state_plan_id" />

        </entity>

    <entity name="PLANS" 
          query="select PLANS.ID, PLANS.BATCH_ID, PLANS.OPERATION, PLANS.NAME, PLANS.DESCRIPTION,
               PLANS.CONTACT_ID, PLANS.PLAN_TYPE_ID, PLANS.AGENCY_ID, PLANS.START_DATE,
               NVL(PLANS.END_DATE,0) END_DATE,
               NVL(PLANS.TRACS_PARENT_PLAN_ID,0) TRACS_PARENT_PLAN_ID,
               NVL(PLANS.STATE_PARENT_PLAN_ID,0) STATE_PARENT_PLAN_ID,
               NVL(PLANS.TRACS_ID,0) TRACS_ID,
               NVL(PLANS.STATE_ID,0) STATE_ID,          
               PLANS.VALID, PLANS.APPLIED,
               NVL(PLANS.COMMENTS,'NULL') COMMENTS from SSOHANI.PLANS" >

        <field column="ID" name="plans_id" />
        <field column="BATCH_ID" name="plans_batch_id" />
        <field column="OPERATION" name="plans_operation" />
        <field column="NAME" name="plans_name" />
        <field column="DESCRIPTION" name="plans_description" />
        <field column="CONTACT_ID" name="plans_contact_id" />
        <field column="PLAN_TYPE_ID" name="plans_plan_type_id" />       
        <field column="AGENCY_ID" name="plans_agency_id" />
        <field column="START_DATE" name="plans_start_date" />
        <field column="END_DATE" name="plans_end_date" />
        <field column="TRACS_PARENT_PLAN_ID" name="plans_tracs_parent_plan_id" />
        <field column="STATE_PARENT_PLAN_ID" name="plans_state_parent_plan_id" />
        <field column="TRACS_ID" name="plans_tracs_id" />
        <field column="STATE_ID" name="plans_state_id" />
        <field column="VALID" name="plans_valid" />
        <field column="APPLIED" name="plans_applied" />
        <field column="COMMENTS" name="plans_comments" />       
    </entity>

</document>   
</dataConfig>
```

and I configured my schema.xml like this...

```
<schema>
<fields>

        <field name="projects_id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="projects_batch_id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="projects_operation" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="projects_name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="projects_description" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="projects_estimated_cost" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="projects_grantor_agency_id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="projects_grantee_agency_id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="projects_project_status_id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="projects_project_type_id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="projects_start_date" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="projects_end_date" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>      
        <field name="projects_tracs_parent_project_id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>       
        <field name="projects_state_parent_project_id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="projects_plan_id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="projects_plan_id_type" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="projects_tracs_id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="projects_state_id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>      
        <field name="projects_valid" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="projects_applied" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="projects_comments" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="projects_generated_plan_id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="projects_tracs_project_id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="projects_state_plan_id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>

                <!--         fields for plan enity -->

        <field name="plans_id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="plans_batch_id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="plans_operation" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="plans_name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="plans_description" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="plans_contact_id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="plans_plan_type_id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="plans_agency_id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="plans_start_date" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="plans_end_date" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="plans_tracs_parent_plan_id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="plans_state_parent_plan_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>       
        <field name="plans_tracs_id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>     
        <field name="plans_state_id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="plans_valid" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="plans_applied" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="plans_comments" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>

    </fields>

    <uniqueKey>projects_id</uniqueKey>
    <uniqueKey>plans_id</uniqueKey>
    <defaultSearchField>projects_id</defaultSearchField>
</schema>
```

and my solrconfig.xml is...

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
      <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="config">/opt/solr/core0/conf/data-config.xml</str>
      </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

now when i am running a full-import command i am getting the following error..

```
Apr 16, 2012 4:11:46 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter upload
WARNING: Error creating document : SolrInputDocument[{projects_tracs_id=projects_tracs_id(1.0)={0}, projects_name=projects_name(1.0)={Minnesota Firearms Safety Training Program}, projects_description=projects_description(1.0)={To train 17,500 students and 425 new instructors at 45 recruiting workshops. Hold one statwide training academy. Award 2,650 recognition awards for length of service.}, projects_comments=projects_comments(1.0)={NULL}, projects_plan_id=projects_plan_id(1.0)={0}, projects_end_date=projects_end_date(1.0)={2002-12-31 00:00:00.0}, projects_tracs_parent_project_id=projects_tracs_parent_project_id(1.0)={0}, projects_plan_id_type=projects_plan_id_type(1.0)={0}, projects_project_status_id=projects_project_status_id(1.0)={4}, projects_state_plan_id=projects_state_plan_id(1.0)={1126}, projects_estimated_cost=projects_estimated_cost(1.0)={600000}, projects_valid=projects_valid(1.0)={N}, projects_grantor_agency_id=projects_grantor_agency_id(1.0)={1154}, projects_start_date=projects_start_date(1.0)={2001-12-31 00:00:00.0}, projects_applied=projects_applied(1.0)={N}, projects_state_id=projects_state_id(1.0)={0}, projects_batch_id=projects_batch_id(1.0)={1433468017}, projects_generated_plan_id=projects_generated_plan_id(1.0)={2050667163}, projects_id=projects_id(1.0)={2009553709}, projects_operation=projects_operation(1.0)={INSERT}, projects_state_parent_project_id=projects_state_parent_project_id(1.0)={0}, projects_grantee_agency_id=projects_grantee_agency_id(1.0)={1235}, projects_tracs_project_id=projects_tracs_project_id(1.0)={1123}, projects_project_type_id=projects_project_type_id(1.0)={3}}]
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: [doc=2009553709] missing required field: plans_applied
    at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:346)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:60)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:115)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter.upload(SolrWriter.java:73)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler$1.upload(DataImportHandler.java:293)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:636)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:268)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:187)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:359)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:427)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:408)
```

solr is not able to read any of the fields of the second entity.
Can anyone help me out of this problem..?
please tell me what mistake i am making while configuring the data-config.xml or schema.xml or both the files..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although from stack trace it looks like one of your Plan documents is missing value in required plans_applied field, I think that the first thing you need to be aware of is that data isn't supposed to be normalized in Solr. It's supposed to be flattened before entering index.

So, instead of indexing those two tables as separate entities, you should create a join (directly in data-config.xml, instead of your queries) between those two tables so that each resulting (join's) table row becomes a Solr document.

That way, when you want to get all data about a single project it'll all be in a single document - no need for joins for such a use case.

In Solr you should embrace redundancy, not relationships and constraints.

Makes sense?

Comment: how to join those two tables and how i should configure my schema.xml..?
i read wiki but not able to understand..so it will be helpful if you can explain me with a small example..
thanks.

Comment: What do you want to be searchable? Only projects and plans or more tables? The point is that you need to flatten the data. Think of result of (Select * from) join query on Projects and Plans. Result is a new temporary table which contains all columns from both tables. That's what you need to do with all tables whose contents you want to search. And then, one row from that big table becomes one Solr document.

Comment: The key is that you answer which tables do you want to be searchable?

Comment: I got your point...actually there is one more table but firstly i am wanting to configure it with the above mentioned ones..

There will be only one input for searching and regarding that input i have to display all the values from the tables..

like if I input an id value and the match is found from the PLANS table..my search should fetch all the details from that table only...

is it possible to do so..?
and I will be very helpful if you can give me an example of joining in solr...I know how to join tables in sql but not able to understand the syntax in solr...

Comment: I'm not sure (from your comment) that you actually got the point. Here is example of flattening the data from a rdb: http://mysolr.com/tips/denormalized-data-structure/

Comment: i tried to configure my data-config.xml but there is a problem in joining the tables. The tables haven't got any association with each other. Each table is a separate entity. So how can i join the tables ?
can you suggest me any alternate solution..?

Comment: I see that you have field PLAN_ID in your Projects table, so the simplest join would be: select * from PROJECTS, PLANS where PROJECTS.PLAN_ID = PLANS.PLAN_ID